# Where can I find the output of exim's 'debug_print'? -- years later

Tags: logging, exim, debug

There is an old thread:

[Where can I find the output of exim's 'debug_print'?](https://serverfault.com/questions/300629/where-can-i-find-the-output-of-exims-debug-print)

(so yes I did search for existing questions, I did find an exact match , but I'm not allowed to comment + it's old and folks don't like resurrecting old posts)

This post ends with:

```
 /usr/sbin/exim4 -bd -d+all -q30m
```

When I followed the logic therein and came up with:

```
/usr/sbin/exim4  -bd -d -q30m  -oX  25:587:10025  -oP  /run/exim4/exim.pid  

/usr/sbin/exim4   -d+all -q30m  -oX  25:587:10025  -oP  /run/exim4/exim.pid  

/usr/sbin/exim4   -v -d -q30m  -oX  25:587:10025  -oP  /run/exim4/exim.pid
```

And various similar combinations:

I also found /etc/exim4/conf.d/main/90_exim4-config_log_selector  (debian) and set

```
# uncomment this for debugging                                                                                                                                                                                                       
MAIN_LOG_SELECTOR == MAIN_LOG_SELECTOR +all -subject -arguments
```

All in all turning on every option I can find.

It starts off well, like the OP

```
exim version 4.94.2 uid=0 gid=0 pid=4193860 D=f7715cfd                                                                                                                                                                               
Support for: crypteq iconv() IPv6 PAM Perl Expand_dlfunc GnuTLS move_frozen_messages Content_Scanning DANE DKIM DNSSEC Event I18N OCSP PIPE_CONNECT PRDR PROXY SOCKS TCP_Fast_Open                                                   
Lookups (built-in):
```

But then just stops outputting anything , it ends like:

```
  776   Start queue run: pid=776                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  776 queue-runner forking for logfile-open                                                                                                                                                                                          
  776 queue-runner forked for logfile-open: 777                                                                                                                                                                                      
  777 postfork: logfile-open                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  776 queue running main directory                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  776 looking in /var/spool/exim4//input                                                                                                                                                                                             
  776 LOG: queue_run MAIN                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  776   End queue run: pid=776                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  776 search_tidyup called                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  776 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Exim pid=776 (queue-runner) terminating with rc=0 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                                                                                                                                            
  774 child 776 ended: status=0x0                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  774   normal exit, 0                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  774 0 queue-runner processes now running
```

And then just sits there. I "feels" like it's forked off a child and it's stderr is not pointing back at my terminal (see above I took off the -bd even though -d should void it)

It's still waiting at my terminal.

But if I send mails (using mail(1)) to legal and illegal addresses and addresses with e.forward files, I see activity in /var/log/exim4/mainlog but nothing appears in the terminal (or anywhere else I can find)...I'm just wanted to see the output of /etc/exim4/conf.d/router/600_exim4-config_userforward     namely:

debug_print = "R: userforward for $local_part@$domain"